# Is return ticket required for travelling on Temporary Resident Visa to Canada?

Tags: air-travel, canada, return-tickets

While there is no IRCC guideline which says a return ticket is a must for temporary visitors to Canada, I have heard stories where the airline did not let the traveller board the flight at country of origin due to no return ticket. Is it a good practice to have a return ticket so that it can be shown if asked by a CBSA staff at the point of entry? I am aware that a visitor can stay up to a maximum of 6 months.

Comment: Are you talking about a Visitor or Resident? These are a little different, a temporary resident may be expected to stay longer than 6 months.

Comment: I'm talking about a visitor. I believe the visa is called temporary resident visa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's not absolutely necessary, but it's definitely good practice, and you need to be able to explain your departure plan.**

All genuine visitors arrive knowing how they are expecting to leave, and most have some kind of booking to go home again. Some don't, for example if you live in the US and are just stopping in Canada to visit before driving home across the border. Some might not know exactly when they are going home, for example visiting a sick relative, but even then they usually have a plan to return home, and probably a ticket.

So in essence, if you don't have a ticket of some kind then you are going to have to explain what your departure plan is quite thoroughly, and provide some sort of documentation to back it up.

Note that a "return" ticket doesn't have to be actually back to your home. If you are going on to a third country, and have a ticket to do that, that will be fine. Likewise if you are driving to a US airport and flying home from there, showing that ticket home will be OK, as it shows your intent to leave Canada.

Comment: For some temporary residents, proof of financial capability to pay for a flight might be enough

Comment: I don't think it's about financial capability. They want to know when you will leave, that you have a plan to do it, and why you haven't bought tickets for it yet.

Comment: I'm not sure a short-haul ticket to a US airport would be sufficient- CBSA has to consider the very real possibility that the US would not permit entry to the foreigner without an onward ticket.

Comment: @DJClayworth I am currently a temporary resident in Canada (for 2 years) and I clearly remember the border agents did not ask me about any flight or proof that I had a specific planned way out of the country (I did not have anything specific planned 2 years ahead). However I was asked if I had enough money (not specifically to leave the country but I assumed that's part of it)